# How to remove space after div in my td when one div uses "relative" position?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**How do I remove the space after my divs in my td ?**

Below is my HTML and CSS. I've tried searching other solutions on stack overflow, but they don't seem to work in this case - maybe because of the "relative" position of the second div.

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="progressBar"></div>       //Updated dynamically using js
        <div class="numericProgress>0%</div>  //Updated dynamically using js
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table
{
table-layout:fixed;
width:100%;
}

table,td,th
{
overflow:auto;
border-collapse:collapse;
text-align:center;
}

.progressBar
{
    width:1%;
    height:30px;
    background: #A8E6F5;
}
.numericProgress 
{
    color: #123123;
    font-size: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -31px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove the extra line; however, I have not yet found a way to keep the value in the center without the number moving as the bar increases (I assume you are using `width:` in the `.progressBar` tag to "fill" the bar).  In the solution I am providing, the number will move and center in the filled area as the bar moves from 0% to 100%.

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="progressBar">
       <div class="numericProgress">0%</div> 
    </div>       

  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table
{
  table-layout:fixed;
  width:100%;
}

table,td,th
{
  overflow:auto;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  text-align:center;
}

.progressBar
{
  width:1%;
  height:30px;
  background: #A8E6F5;
}

.numericProgress 
{
  color: #123123;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
}
```

View [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvfP9/1/) here.

If I come across a solution that keeps the % centered, I will edit my answer to reflect the new findings.

EDIT: the update CSS block should work now :). Kudos to @badAdviceGuy for his comment!

Comment: If you give .numericProgress position:absolute and left:50% it should center it.